# Check my SSRS report if it's empty from code

Tags: c#, web-services, ssrs-2008, reportviewer2008

I'm loading  my reports that I have done using SSRS,by code(C#),but i need to check if report is empty or not!!!

how can i get that?!!
my code that Im using is:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(RptInstance.FileName))
            {
                string ReportName = RptInstance.FileName.Replace(".rpt", "");
                reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = string.Format("{0}{1}", Settings.Default.ReportPath, ReportName);
                reportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(paramList);
                reportViewer.ServerReport.Timeout = Timeout;

                string mimeType, encoding, extension, deviceInfo;
                string[] streamIds = null;
                Warning[] warnings = null;
                deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo><SimplePageHeaders>True</SimplePageHeaders></DeviceInfo>";

                byte[] bytes = reportViewer.ServerReport.Render(RptInstance.PDF ? "PDF" : "Excel", deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);
                RptInstance.State = true;
                //SaveData(Report.FileName, bytes, string.Format(@"C:\temp\{0}.{1}", ReportName, isPdf ? "pdf" : "xlsx"));

                SaveData(string.Format("{0}_{1}.{2}", ReportName, Guid.NewGuid(), RptInstance.PDF ? "pdf" : "xlsx"), bytes, DirectoryName);
            }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean report is empty? Do you mean for the parameters you passed your dataset has no records?

Comment: @nunespascal exactly that what i mean

Answer (score 2):

DataSets are internal to a report. There is no external API to find the number of records returned by a particular dataset for a given report parameters.

There are two approaches you can take to solve the problem:

1 . Use a `LocalReport`

Create your DataSet in C# code, check if it has rows, and then give this as a DataSource to SSRS.

```
ReportDataSource ds = new ReportDataSource(dsName, data);
ReportGenerator gen = new ReportGenerator(data, dsName);
reportViewer.Reset();
reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(ds);
reportViewer.LocalReport.DisplayName = displayName;
reportViewer.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(gen.GeneraReport());
```

Refer : [Dynamic Reports with Reporting Services](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/56817/Dynamic-Reports-with-Reporting-Services)

2 . Download your report as a CSV. This will give you the raw data for each DataSource for your set of parameters. Here you can check the number of rows returned.

Comment: using the second solution by downloading the reports as CSV,how can i know the raw data for each dataSource?!!,inorder to check the number of rows?!!    thanks in advance

Comment: Save your report as a CSV and see, for each data source it will write out the data. Counting the number of lines in a CSV file should be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my ninja way of doing it.

Set every controls Hidden property to an Expression that hides the control when the DataSet has no records:

```
=Rownumber("TransactionsByAccountAndEffDate") = 0
```

In the Report I also insert a TextBox and set its Hidden property to let people know when the report has no data:

[image]

```
=Rownumber("TransactionsByAccountAndEffDate") > 0
```

**Then when I generate the report that has no data, all the controls will be hidden and this makes the size of the file tiny:**

[image]

After I've created the report in code I simple check the file size, to see if its tiny:

```
var length = new System.IO.FileInfo(path).Length;
```