# How to check if a report returned by SSRS web services is empty or not

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have an service that integrates with `SSRS 2012` to build reports and mail them. The service invokes the `SSRS` web services to get the report stream.

For one type of report it needs to check if the report is not empty before send it.

How can this be done in a abstract way, without duplicating the query inside the report, or analyzing the report content?

Update:
Render method returns warnings. Would it be possible to send a specific warning from the report? I try raise an warning in the dataset query but still got null on the warnings parameter. Probably is intent only for service warnings. Documentation doesn't add much.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're getting a byte array from the SSRS server you could try to determine what the minimum length of a valid report is. Other than that I'd say examining the contents seems like the best option.

Comment: The idea is to do it in an abstract way, without analyzing report content.
Observing the length easily fails if the format changes of if some image is embedded.

Comment: Going to be hard to do this abstractly as you have probably already surmised. The SSRS web service doesn't really have a mechanism to indicate that a form was populated or data was available to it.  You could have an if statement that always says "No Data" with no other page formatting if there are no datasets so the returned size is always the same regardless of data.  You could also do local reports and generate your dataset and pass the whole dataset to SSRS if it is valid, but I don't really like that solution as much.

Comment: I still don't see another ways to do it too. I will dig into your second solution. Tks.

Comment: It is possible to open an external dataset from the web service, to see if it has nay rows?

Comment: It isn't there is no API or any other way to get any information about the dataset from the webservice.  This post gives some info about localreport 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247466/check-my-ssrs-report-if-its-empty-from-code